# Blank Screen Android 2.2 Google Maps v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

**EDIT :**

I transferred my 20+ projects that **tries** to use Google Maps for Android v2. After changing keys and stuff, now, it works. I don't know what made this work, but thank you all. I got one keystore, the key is right. I guess it magically fixed somehow. Well, thanks guys.

I'm doing searches for 2 days and I couldn't fix this problem. I did everything, yet, this application can not work.

I want my application to work on Android 2.2 and above. Like it says "if you create your app in level 8, it'll support 95% of market".

Here are my screenshots and source codes:

I'm pasting the source code which is the easiest to get. I took this from web.

Here's the output of the command

```
keytool -list -keystore <path>
```

> ```
> *****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
> * The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
> * has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
> * you must provide your keystore password.                  *
> *****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
> ```
>
> Keystore type: JKS Keystore provider: SUN

```
Your keystore contains 1 entry

androiddebugkey, 15.Mar.2013, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xxx
```

**main.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyDim-x5Gxxx"
/>
```

**manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidhive.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!-- Add Google Map Library -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidGoogleMapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <!-- Allow to connect with internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

**java file** (no need to paste it all, but I guess it's best to paste it all)

http://pastebin.com/yF95Rcbd

Here are my screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IHTG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdaDs.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfKEJ.png

I'm trying to compile this app to Android 4.2.2, but I tried and want to make it work in 2.2 and above.

Here's the Android tab of the properties window just to make sure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiYJm.png

Here's my log

```
03-20 07:01:20.145: W/System.err(956):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-20 07:01:20.665: W/System.err(956): IOException processing: 26
03-20 07:01:20.665: W/System.err(956): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
03-20 07:01:20.665: W/System.err(956):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
03-20 07:01:20.675: W/System.err(956):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
03-20 07:01:20.675: W/System.err(956):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
03-20 07:01:20.675: W/System.err(956):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
03-20 07:01:20.675: W/System.err(956):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
```

These lines repeat all the time.

Thank you very much.
    Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" error made
    me delete the blank lines. Sorry for the messed up codes.

Comment: Google Maps V2 API stopped service. Use Google Maps V3 API instead.

Comment: I'm trying to use Google Maps for Android v2

Comment: @Janmejoy Sadly, no. Still waiting.

Answer (score 1):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiYJm.png
See the snapshot. You did not add Google Play Services library that is require for displaying Google Android Map V2. Please download and add that library and then try again.

Please also see the target. Your target is 4.2.2 and your are accessing it on 2.2. Change the target to 2.2 and use support fragment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue,

- Open your Google APIs Console
- Choose API Access
- Edit allowed Android apps from your API Key
- Change the package name with your package name
- Example: 00:06:A5:0E:04:A2:1E:8F:FE:6B:7F:46:23:C3:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;com.example.androidmapview

Answer (score 0):

Working with android mapapi v2 ,the main reason is you must add play service to your app,like below :

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapview.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidmapview.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Use fragment class in Layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

And change your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidmapview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapview.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidmapview.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidmapview.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></meta-data>
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

in activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

For more info check the [link](http://seasonofrejoice.blogspot.in/) which will explain you in details about api v2

Comment: Done that. Still nothing but a blank screen with grids.

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville it will show you blank in emulator try in device!

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville it will ask for update of play services..So better check in device!!

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville you can update the play services only from device,if you will check in device it will work!!

Comment: Tried it now. Same as emulator. Blank screen with grids.

Comment: I did. Still nothing. I added my Logcat log in the post. I hope this can help you identify the problem.

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville i have edited almost the complete code !! hope it will work now!!

Comment: Here's the full source code. I'm trying for 2 days. Without sleep, without a single piece of happiness, yet I can't make this work... I uploaded it here: http://emrey.p.ht/AndroidGoogleMaps.zip Thank you very much.

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville let me check i will let you know!!

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville i have attached one link did you check that!!it is having the complete code..try with that basic code !!

Comment: You mean this? http://seasonofrejoice.blogspot.in/ I tried tutorials like this maybe 10 times. They all fail to work. There's something wrong with me I guess.

Comment: yes..did you create the api followed by sha1 fingerprint;package name

Comment: And, I can't even import "import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;", to be honest.

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville add the above code only remove everything in activity,then add fragment class in layout then the manifest..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing permissions and meta-data for API KEY.

Read this carefully: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: I accidentally deleted my manifest file because of the stackoverflow code error. I know you guys are going to curse me, but still the same thing. Errors are the same, too.

Comment: Comapre your manifest with https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/source/browse/android-maps-extensions-demo/AndroidManifest.xml and remove android:apiKey="AIzaSyDim-x5Gxxx" from main.xml

Comment: App crashes when I do this.

Comment: You are not trying to use maps api v2 properly. Start a new, empty project and follow instructions in the link in my answer.

Comment: I did it lots of times. I'll do it again now and upload the resulting project. I think I have an issue with my key, but I'm doing it again and posting you the link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my blank screen problem with zoom in/out buttons like that.(it happens after I changed my package name)

1. Delete the keystore file
2. Create a new keystore file
3. Get SHA1 fingerprint
4. Go to API Console
5. Create a new Android App.
6. Paste your fingerprint
7. Use the given API Key in your Manifest File

That worked for me