# Google maps v2 blank screen

Tags: android, google-maps

Google map blank screen can someone help me out spent a week  now still the same prob
before i give up on it
here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ezamarichard.software.icytrey"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.ezamarichard.software.icytrey.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.ezamarichard.software.icytrey.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/><br/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use  
Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ezamarichard.software.icytrey.Google"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="**AIzaSyDg3COCl-HIDDEN-7i8zpr9ru2NxdeYk**" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

before giving up may be somebody can help me out

---

my layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**am still new to this site so my posting of the code is not okay as you can see**
I tried out these links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658526/google-maps-android-v2-blank-screen/), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993592/google-maps-are-being-show-as-blank-screen/), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516476/blank-screen-android-2-2-google-maps-v2/) and [most especially this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048381/google-maps-api-v2-shows-blank-map) but still nothing

Comment: pls format your post.

Comment: @Novocaine88 he talks about android, not web api

Comment: Thanks man!
You should give an up vote also..

Answer (score 0):

I will post what solved this same error in my case for further readers:

As pointed out, when the map shows blank, we're facing an auth problem. What usually solves the problem is to delete the debug.keysore file, get a new one building the project again, unistall the application on device and create (or update) a new android key on the google apis console with the new fingerprint.

My mistake was that the first time I re-installed the app on the device it had the old api-key in the manifest file, and for some reasons even updating it with the new one didn't change it!

So my suggestion is to re-install the app only after having changed the api-key on the manifest.